# Strange results of evaluating in statement for list and set by means of timeit module

Tags: python, python-3.x, timeit

Trying to evaluate performance of `in` statement for both: `set` and `list`. I know that I can do it with module `time`, but I want to try `timeit` module. 
So my code is next:

```
from timeit import Timer


def func_to_test(val, s):
    return val in s

if __name__ == "__main__":
    val = 346
    n = 100000
    s = set([x for x in range(n)])
    l = [x for x in range(n)]
    list_timer = Timer("func_to_test(%s, %s)" % (val, l), "from __main__ import func_to_test")
    set_timer = Timer("func_to_test(%s, %s)" % (val, s), "from __main__ import func_to_test")
    print(list_timer.timeit(100))
    print(set_timer.timeit(100))
```

The output is:

```
0.1953735960000813
0.6675883569996586
```

But why `in` statement for `list` "has" better performance than `set`?
I know that it's not, but why there are these results with `timeit` module?

Comment: Try using a bigger n, the constant factors with the set in this case are likely just somewhat high, so it won't grow slower than l for a small n

Answer (score 2):

Your setup statement imports `func_to_test`, but it doesn't do anything else. Therefore, the actual timing tests are timing not only the time it takes for a membership test, but also the time it takes to create a list (for the list test) or a list *and* a set (for the set test). Create the iterable in the setup statement, and the issue disappears:

```
>>> import timeit
>>> timeit.timeit('346 in s', setup='s=list(range(100000))')
9.412489017458922
>>> timeit.timeit('346 in s', setup='s=set(list(range(100000)))')
0.08872845571155352
>>> timeit.timeit('346 in s', setup='s=set(range(100000))')
0.09335872296618675
```

Comment: Thanks, you point out at correct way of timing. But why my code produces such results?

Comment: @Litwisha - Because your code is looking at how long it takes to create a list and test for membership, or create a list, create a set, and test for membership, not just how long it takes to test for membership.

Comment: that's a little strange to me. Because list and set creating is evaluating in main block, not in `func_to_test`.